# Select two Drowndown values using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a dropwdown where i need to fetch values using Jquery.

Please see the copy pasted lines from my watch:

```
-       $("[id$='ddlEmployee']")    {...}   Object
+       [Methods]       
+       [0] {Count = 4} DispHTMLSelectElement
+       [1] {Count = 4} DispHTMLSelectElement
+       context {object}    DispHTMLDocument
        jquery  "1.7.2" String
        length  2   Number
+       prevObject  {...}   Object
        selector    "[id$='ddlEmployee']"   String
```

The control name is  ddlEmployee, Since there are two ddlEmployees in same page it has two arrays [0] and [1].. that you can see from above figure

Each array has selected value. (first and second dropdown of that page).

I want get selected value of each dropdown

I tried below : but not worked

1. $("[id$='ddlEmployee']")[0].value  this value will always the first dropdown first item
2. $("[id$='ddlEmployee']")[0][0].value this is also same as above first dropdown first item
3. $("[id$='ddlEmployee']")[0][0].val() Object doesn't support this property or method error
4. $("[id$='ddlEmployee']")[0].val()    Object doesn't support this property or method Error
5. $("[id$='ddlEmployee']")[1].val()    Object doesn't support this property or method Error
6. $("[id$='ddlEmployee']").text()  " -Select- value1 value2 value3 -Select- value1  value2 value3" String
7. $("[id$='ddlEmployee']")[0].text()   Object doesn't support this property or method  Error
8. $("[id$='ddlEmployee']")[1].text()   Object doesn't support this property or method  Error

Only for 6th point i am getting some value. But that is not enough to distinguish between the selected values of which dropdown.

How to write a code , select values of first and second dropdown?

Please see the HTML Code below:

```
<DIV class="datagrid margin-10px-left margin-10px-right"><DIV>
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 100%; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse" id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf_ctl00_gdvDoa class=datagrid border=1 rules=all cellSpacing=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TH style="WIDTH: 90px" scope=col>DOA Name *</TH>
<TH scope=col>DOA For</TH>
<TH style="WIDTH: 80px" scope=col>Start Date *</TH>
<TH style="WIDTH: 80px" scope=col>End Date *</TH>
<TH scope=col>Remarks</TH>
<TH scope=col>&nbsp;</TH></TR>
<TR>
<TD><INPUT id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf_ctl00_gdvDoa_ctl02_txtName class=validate[DOAGridrequired] value="Fin Jack Uppal" readOnly type=text name=ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf$ctl00$gdvDoa$ctl02$txtName jQuery17205721116313179826="5"> <A id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf_ctl00_gdvDoa_ctl02_lnkAddEmployee class=margin-20px-left href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf$ctl00$gdvDoa$ctl02$lnkAddEmployee','')">Select</A> <!-- Added for Grid Level Ajax    --><!-- End of Grid Level Ajax  --></TD>
<TD><SELECT style="WIDTH: 120px" id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf_ctl00_gdvDoa_ctl02_ddlDOAFor class=validate[required] name=ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf$ctl00$gdvDoa$ctl02$ddlDOAFor jQuery17205721116313179826="6"> <OPTION value=0>- Select -</OPTION> <OPTION selected value=TravelAuthorization>TravelAuthorization</OPTION> <OPTION value=ExpenseReporting>ExpenseReporting</OPTION></SELECT> </TD>
<TD><INPUT id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf_ctl00_gdvDoa_ctl02_txtStartDate class=validate[DOADaterequired,DOApast[NOW],DOAdateRange[grp1],DateAddedXDays[21],custom[dd/mm/yyyy]] value=27/09/2012 type=text name=ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf$ctl00$gdvDoa$ctl02$txtStartDate jQuery17205721116313179826="7"> <INPUT style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf_ctl00_gdvDoa_ctl02_imgCal src="/Style%20Library/images/icon-cal.gif" type=image name=ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf$ctl00$gdvDoa$ctl02$imgCal> </TD>
<TD><INPUT id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf_ctl00_gdvDoa_ctl02_txtEndDate class=validate[DOADaterequired,DOApast[NOW],DOAdateRange[grp1],DateAddedXDays[21],custom[dd/mm/yyyy]] value=27/09/2012 type=text name=ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf$ctl00$gdvDoa$ctl02$txtEndDate jQuery17205721116313179826="8"> <INPUT style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf_ctl00_gdvDoa_ctl02_imgCal3 src="/Style%20Library/images/icon-cal.gif" type=image name=ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf$ctl00$gdvDoa$ctl02$imgCal3> </TD>
<TD><TEXTAREA style="WIDTH: 100%" id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf_ctl00_gdvDoa_ctl02_txtRemark class="validate[maxSize[250],DOARemarksInsidePage ]" rows=2 cols=20 name=ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf$ctl00$gdvDoa$ctl02$txtRemark jQuery17205721116313179826="9"></TEXTAREA> </TD>
<TD><A href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf$ctl00$gdvDoa','Select$0')"><IMG title="Remove row" border=0 src="/Style Library/images/icon-delete.gif"></A></TD></TR>
<TR style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #f2f2f2" class=alt>
<TD><INPUT id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf_ctl00_gdvDoa_ctl03_txtName class=validate[DOAGridrequired] value="CCA Kanokporn Choochan" readOnly type=text name=ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf$ctl00$gdvDoa$ctl03$txtName jQuery17205721116313179826="10"> <A id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf_ctl00_gdvDoa_ctl03_lnkAddEmployee class=margin-20px-left href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf$ctl00$gdvDoa$ctl03$lnkAddEmployee','')">Select</A> <!-- Added for Grid Level Ajax    --><!-- End of Grid Level Ajax  --></TD>
<TD><SELECT style="WIDTH: 120px" id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf_ctl00_gdvDoa_ctl03_ddlDOAFor class=validate[required] name=ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf$ctl00$gdvDoa$ctl03$ddlDOAFor jQuery17205721116313179826="11"> <OPTION value=0>- Select -</OPTION> <OPTION selected value=TravelAuthorization>TravelAuthorization</OPTION> <OPTION value=ExpenseReporting>ExpenseReporting</OPTION></SELECT> </TD>
<TD><INPUT id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf_ctl00_gdvDoa_ctl03_txtStartDate class=validate[DOADaterequired,DOApast[NOW],DOAdateRange[grp1],DateAddedXDays[21],custom[dd/mm/yyyy]] value=27/09/2012 type=text name=ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf$ctl00$gdvDoa$ctl03$txtStartDate jQuery17205721116313179826="12"> <INPUT style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf_ctl00_gdvDoa_ctl03_imgCal src="/Style%20Library/images/icon-cal.gif" type=image name=ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf$ctl00$gdvDoa$ctl03$imgCal> </TD>
<TD><INPUT id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf_ctl00_gdvDoa_ctl03_txtEndDate class=validate[DOADaterequired,DOApast[NOW],DOAdateRange[grp1],DateAddedXDays[21],custom[dd/mm/yyyy]] value=27/09/2012 type=text name=ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf$ctl00$gdvDoa$ctl03$txtEndDate jQuery17205721116313179826="13"> <INPUT style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf_ctl00_gdvDoa_ctl03_imgCal3 src="/Style%20Library/images/icon-cal.gif" type=image name=ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf$ctl00$gdvDoa$ctl03$imgCal3> </TD>
<TD><TEXTAREA style="WIDTH: 100%" id=ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf_ctl00_gdvDoa_ctl03_txtRemark class="validate[maxSize[250],DOARemarksInsidePage ]" rows=2 cols=20 name=ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf$ctl00$gdvDoa$ctl03$txtRemark jQuery17205721116313179826="14"></TEXTAREA> </TD>
<TD><A href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$SPWebPartManager$g_00ed9bd7_7fe8_45be_a81e_9898c9819caf$ctl00$gdvDoa','Select$1')"><IMG title="Remove row" border=0 src="/Style Library/images/icon-delete.gif"></A></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV></DIV>
```

Comment: Holy long IDs, Batman! What on Earth is going on with your markup?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/4ePnt/)

Using `[ ]` indexing returns the underlying DOM object, which isn't a jQuery object and therefore doesnt support the jQuery methods. Filter the set using the jQuery method [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$("[id$='ddlEmployee']").eq(0).val();
$("[id$='ddlEmployee']").eq(1).val();
```

Comment: Also [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first) and [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last)

Comment: No its not working .. the above code only taking values of first dropdowns first and second item...not selected values of first and second dropdown

Comment: @Pete Can you include the relevant section of html in your post?

Comment: Lol. Thanks for getting rid of the unnecessary parts. It's still huge though, and not very well formatted. A couple of comments...html attributes must be surrounded by `' '` marks. Most of yours aren't. IDs should also be unique. I can't even tell if yours are because they're so long. Please create a *small* test-case which reproduces the error on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). (p.s. I added a working demo, you can modify that one rather than starting from scratch)